# Is there a way to wrap a react component and use it in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, monaco-editor, code-editor

I am a newbie in the react and react-native. Currently, I am working on building a code editor for IOS using react-native. I found the Monaco code editor, yet it does not support mobile usage. Is there a way I can somehow wrap it and use it in react-native? Or is there any other way I can do it?

Comment: React native does not support html and css directly.

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/react-monaco-editor/react-monaco-editor